# Boostrapvalidator not fired simple form

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to validate my form, the form is having simple elements:

but however, the boostrap validator is not called. https://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/24hzp7mk/16/

```
    $('#form_hr').bootstrapValidator({
```

i don' t know where the problem is coming from, can you help me out

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a click event to fire the validate I guess, try this add to the end of your js  `$(document).ready(function()...` :

```
    $('#btnsave').click(function() {
            $('#form_hr').bootstrapValidator('validate');
    });
```

Also if you want to validate field, you need to use their name attribute (ex: `name="hr_birthdate"`) like:

```
<input id="hr_birthdate" name="hr_birthdate" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Please select your birthdate" style="width:100%;" value="" />
```

Try this one for those update:

https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/s3fdej7L/

Comment: @dtjmsy no problem, happy to help